# Using reply_body_max_size

Tags: squid

I have one question regarding the use of `reply_body_max_size`? I'm using squid 3.3.8 and I'm trying to set download limit for my `special_group` and `officers_group` in my configuration file below:

```
........
........
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/24
acl special group src 192.168.0.1
.......
.......
reply_body_max_size 10 MB localnet
reply_body_max_size 300 MB special_group
......
.......
```

The above will always take the first as the download limit and ignores the second. I want to know why the second download limit 'reply_body_max_size 300 MB special_group did'nt work?

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/OrderIsImportant

Your config line 3 says that all requests from client in 192.168.0.0/24 are to use 10MB max size.

Your config line 4 applies to clients who are not matched by that earlier line AND have the IP address 192.168.0.1. Which is of course nobody.

You can either order your reply_body_max_size lines with the exception first, or alter the first lines' boolean condition by adding !special_group to the end of that line.